# Want to Create a Common WebAPI Login That Many Sites Will Use

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

We need to create a simple site that is just for authentication/authorization.  It will use the latest OAuth and OWIN and Microsoft Identity.  I am assuming WebAPI would be the way to go but I am new to it and MVC in general so let me know if a better way is out there.

I have created a simple **Login Service Web API** that has an `Account` controller.  Here is the `Login` action I will use:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl) {
  ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
  return View();
}
```

And here is a simple **Client Web App** that will call the **Login Service App**.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index() {
  var client = new HttpClient();
  var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:19604/Account/Login");
  string thing = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

  return Content(thing);
}
```

This returns me the view I am wanting with `Email`, `Password`, `Remember me` and such.  However, the buttons do not work.  When I click the `Login` button I get a **404** on `/Account/Login`.  I suspect this is because the WebAPI Controller is no longer hooked up and the client side does not have an `Account` controller.

Is the `return Content(thing);` causing the problem and breaking it?
Do I need to hard-code the actions on the Login Service to go to specific URLs?
Or is what I am wanting to do just not possible?

In the end, I will want this **Login Service Web API** to return me the credentials/token with the logged in users claims as if I had logged in via the client app itself.

Comment: You may find this article useful for creating a Web API for authenticating users: http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/. One thing to remember is the Web API is not related to the views on your website, so you Web API will not return `View()`. Instead, you should use the `BadRequest`, `Ok`, etc, methods on the `ApiController` class.

Comment: @MotoSV Thank you very much for this link.  Sorry for the delay, been busy on other projects.  I think this will help.  Can't wait for the 6th and final post to see how he would integrate it.

Comment: Glad to help. I am also currently looking into creating a common "identity" API and this tutorial is proving to be very useful and informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your `WebApi controllers`, ***don't return a view***. They return `IHttpActionResult` (put in more sensible way, they return HTTP codes)

The `Login` button preferably goes to the `login action of the account controller` in the Mvc context.

You cannot directly do what you want to unless you do it in a customised way.

For e.g.

1. On clicking the `Login` button, redirect the call to a `private method` within the controller itself.
2. Call the login method of the WebApi project inside this private method.
3. If login succeeds, (say if ***HTTP 200*** is returned), redirect the call to a corresponding `Mvc controller`. If not, (say, on ***HTTP 404*** errors) go to a `custom error page`.

Or else, you can implement a custom membership. Decorate the controller with [**CustomMembershipAttribute**] ([here](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/b11a280114-Understanding-ASP.NET-MVC-Filters-and-Attributes.html)) attribute. See [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates)

***As a side note:***
I prefer using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) rather than creating a new instance of `HttpClient` and using it. The code looks clumsy to me ;)